# weird working of CASE funtion in mySQL

Tags: mysql, case

I am hoping to get some insight on how mySQL works by this question.
So I wanted to get the median of the elements in a certain column. See the problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20). What I had been trying to do was get the total number of rows in a variable `@ct` and derive a table in which all the rows are numbered and sorted by the values of the column in question.
Then I simply query for the average of column whose rows satisfy a criteria and the criteria is subject to whether `@ct` is odd or even. Below is the working code for that.

```
SET @ct := (select count(*) from STATION); %This stores the number of rows
SET @rowNum :=0; %This will be used to save row number for each row.


SELECT AVG(q.LAT_N) 

FROM (SELECT LAT_N,(@rowNum:=@rowNum+1) n FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N) AS q

WHERE q.n = (CASE @ct%2 WHEN 1 THEN (@ct+1)/2 ELSE @ct/2 OR (@ct+1)/2 END)
```

The weird thing is when in the last line instead of using OR to sort of pair two values I do this,

```
 WHERE q.n = (CASE @ct%2 WHEN 1 THEN (@ct+1)/2 ELSE (@ct/2,(@ct+1)/2) END)
```

OR

```
WHERE q.n IN (CASE @ct%2 WHEN 1 THEN (@ct+1)/2 ELSE (@ct/2,(@ct+1)/2) END)
```

I keep getting syntax error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`
Any idea what is going on? Am I missing some basic syntax rule?
I tried the same thing with `IF` function as well.

Comment: I don't think _(@ct/2,(@ct+1)/2)_ is a valid expression because of the comma. It would evaluate to two columns and you are testing against one column

Comment: but don't we do that in the `IN` clause?

Comment: `IN` only tests against multiple rows, not multiple columns. You can think of it as row vector vs. column vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your approach.

Your first query will not work for even counts because `@ct/2 OR (@ct+1)/2` will always return `1` (`TRUE`). And so you will always get the least value.

Your second WHERE condition doesn't work, because a CASE expression cannot return multiple columns. What you can do is to use a BETWEEN condition:

```
WHERE q.n BETWEEN (CASE @ct%2 WHEN 1 THEN (@ct+1)/2 ELSE @ct/2 END)
              AND (CASE @ct%2 WHEN 1 THEN (@ct+1)/2 ELSE (@ct+1)/2 END)
```

Or

```
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN @ct%2
        THEN q.n = (@ct+1)/2
        ELSE q.n BETWEEN @ct/2 AND (@ct+1)/2
    END
```

However `(@ct+1)/2` is wrong for even counts and should be `@ct/2+1`.

But you don't even need a CASE expression. You can also just use

```
WHERE q.n BETWEEN @ct/2
              AND @ct/2+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to your question. But I think it is a solution to your problem.

```
SET @ct := (select count(*) from STATION);
SET @rowNum :=0; 
SET @start := floor((@ct+1)/2);
SET @end := ceil((@ct+1)/2);

SELECT AVG(q.LAT_N) 

FROM (SELECT LAT_N,(@rowNum:=@rowNum+1) n FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N) AS q

WHERE q.n in(@start,@end);
```

Please, try it.

Comment: Thanks but the code that I have posted actually works . I just wanted to know why it doesn't work with the other way as  I have posted.